# How I make a pointer over the MapView with NativeScript and Angular2?

Tags: google-maps, angular, android-mapview, nativescript

My location with longitude and latitude is working but I need to make a pointer over there, is it possible? I am using NativeScript, Angular2 and NativeScript plugin for Google Maps SDK (nativescript-google-sdk)

**file.ts**

```
import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry'; 
registerElement("MapView", () => require("nativescript-google-maps-sdk").MapView);
```

**file.xml**

```
<MapView [latitude]="configService.unitPreview.latitude" [longitude]="configService.unitPreview.longitude"
                            zoom="17" bearing="0"
                            tilt="0" (mapReady)="OnMapReady"
                            (markerSelect)="onMarkerSelect"
                            (cameraChanged)="onCameraChanged">
                </MapView>
```

[map_without_pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99XRy.jpg)

[map_with_pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIEYM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `addMarker` method to add Markers in the map. You could review my example below, where have been shown, how to do that.

`app,component.html`

```
 <GridLayout>
        <MapView (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"  ></MapView> 
 </GridLayout>
```

`app.com-ponent.ts`

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'; 
var mapsModule = require("nativescript-google-maps-sdk");


@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild("MapView") mapView: ElementRef;
    constructor(){

    }
    //Map events
    onMapReady = (event) => {
        console.log("Map Ready");
        var map =event.object;
        var marker = new mapsModule.Marker();
        marker.position = mapsModule.Position.positionFromLatLng(48.87, 2.35);
        marker.title = "Sydney";
        marker.snippet = "Australia";
        marker.userData = { index : 1};
        map.addMarker(marker);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank's Nikolay. I changed the icon of marker too...

`var image = new ImageModule.Image();
var imageSource = imageSourceModule.fromResource("icon");
image.imageSource = imageSource;
marker.icon = image;`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible show the real traffic like image bellow?

[traffic_real_time.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL7SM.png)